# Key Error when trying to get multiple indicators from OECD API :

Tags: pandas, indexing, python-requests

I'm trying to download data from the OECD [API](https://data.oecd.org/api/sdmx-json-documentation/) into python with the following code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

base = 'http://stats.oecd.org/sdmx-json/data/'
param = [('dataset', 'QNA'),
         ('country', ''),
         ('indicators', 'B1_GE.GYSA'),
         ('freq', 'Q'),
         ('start_period=2016-Q4','?startTime=2016-Q4')
        ]

series = '.'.join(x[1] for x in param[1:-1])
url = '{}{}/{}{}'.format(base, param[0][1], series, param[-1][1])

r = requests.get(url).json()

date_list = r['structure']['dimensions']['observation'][0]['values']
dates = pd.to_datetime([x['id'] for x in date_list])

areas = [v['name'] for v in r['structure']['dimensions']['series'][0]['values']]

title = r['structure']['dimensions']['series'][1]['values'][0]['name']

df = pd.DataFrame()

for i, area in enumerate(areas):
    s_key = '{}:0:0:0'.format(i)
    s_list = r['dataSets'][0]['series'][s_key]['observations']
    df[area] = pd.Series([s_list[val][0] for val in sorted(s_list, key=int)])
    df[area] = (((df[area] / df[area].shift()) ** 4) - 1) * 100


df.index = dates
df = df.dropna()
df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\pedro.salgado\\Documents\\Data\\OECD.csv", sep=";")
```

I'm having 2 problems at the moment:

1. The `df.index = dates` does not work and i get the following error:

> File
> "C:/Users/pedro.salgado/PycharmProjects/Chico_Municipios/OECD.py",
> line 34, in 
> df.index = dates

File "C:\Users\pedro.salgado\PycharmProjects\Chico_Municipios\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",

> line 3627, in **setattr**
> return object.**setattr**(self, name, value)

File "pandas_libs\properties.pyx", line 69, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.**set**

> 

File "C:\Users\pedro.salgado\PycharmProjects\Chico_Municipios\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",

> line 559, in _set_axis
> self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)

File "C:\Users\pedro.salgado\PycharmProjects\Chico_Municipios\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py",

> line 3074, in set_axis
> (old_len, new_len))

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 75 elements, new values have 76 elements

Apparently the indexing is not working because the data row has one more value than the `df`, but i'm no sure what's the easiest way to fix it. When i don't index the `df` the code works just fine. Any ideas?

2. After fixing problem nº1, the script is able to download my data. However when I try to get multiple indicadors at the same time by changing the code to:

`('indicators', 'B1_GE.GPSA+VIXOBSA')`

It crashes and I get another error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:/Users/pedro.salgado/PycharmProjects/Chico_Municipios/OECD.py",
> line 29, in 
> s_list = r['dataSets'][0]['series'][s_key]['observations']

KeyError: '51:0:0:0'